# How to split a string by multiple delimiters

Tags: go

I want to parse a string xxxxx:yyyyy:zzz.aaa.bbb.cc:dd:ee:ff to a struct in Go, how can I do it with multiple delimiter ':' and '.'.

Edit:

I want to split the string "xxxxx:yyyyy:zzz.aaa.bbb.cc:dd" into below struct type

```
type Target struct {
    Service string
    Type    string
    Domain  string
    Plan    string
    Host    string
    Region  string
    Other   string
}
```

So that

```
Service = xxxxx 
Type = yyyyy 
Domain = zzzz 
Plan = aaa 
Host = bbb 
Region = cc 
Other = dd
```

Comment: Please give a more complete example. This is really the same as in any other language but without seeing what you want to assign to it's not possible to fully answer your question. The basic thing is, split on one, then split on the other.

Comment: Sorry about that       
Ok I want to split the string "xxxxx:yyyyy:zzz.aaa.bbb.cc:dd" into below struct
type sample Struct{

    Service string
    Type string 
    Domain string 
    Plan string
    Host string 
    Region string
    Other string 
}

So that Service = xxxxx
Type = yyyyy
Domain = zzzz
Plan = aaa
Host = bbb
Region = cc
Other = dd

Answer (score 63):

You may use

```
strings.FieldsFunc(input, Split)
```

Try it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/k3MY6bJye1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    input := `xxxxx:yyyyy:zzz.aaa.bbb.cc:dd:ee:ff`
    a := strings.FieldsFunc(input, Split)
    t := Target{a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6]}
    fmt.Println(t) // {xxxxx yyyyy zzz aaa bbb cc dd}
}
func Split(r rune) bool {
    return r == ':' || r == '.'
}

type Target struct {
    Service string
    Type    string
    Domain  string
    Plan    string
    Host    string
    Region  string
    Other   string
}
```

output:

```
{xxxxx yyyyy zzz aaa bbb cc dd}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use regex for splitting your string

```
import "regexp"

func splitWord(word string) []string {
    array := regexp.MustCompile("[\\:\\,\\.\\s]+").Split(word, -1)
    return array
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use this function, which can split a string by multiple runes:

```golang
import "fmt"
import "strings"

func SplitAny(s string, seps string) []string {
    splitter := func(r rune) bool {
        return strings.ContainsRune(seps, r)
    }
    return strings.FieldsFunc(s, splitter)
}

func main() {
    words := SplitAny("xxxxx:yyyyy:zzz.aaa.bbb.cc:dd:ee:ff", ".:")
    fmt.Println(strings.Join(words, " "))
}
```

Output:

```
xxxxx yyyyy zzz aaa bbb cc dd ee ff
```

Or even with one line of code:

```golang
words := strings.FieldsFunc(s, func(r rune) bool { return strings.ContainsRune(" .:", r) })
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generic function that will take a string as a set of runes to split on.

```
func Splitter(s string, splits string) []string {
    m := make(map[rune]int)
    for _, r := range splits {
        m[r] = 1
    }

    splitter := func(r rune) bool {
        return m[r] == 1
    }

    return strings.FieldsFunc(s, splitter)
}

func TestSplit() {
    words := Splitter("orange apple-banana", " -")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Alright. This isn't a very elegant solution but it should at least get you started and works for the specific example you've given. In reality you'd probably want to add some error handling or generalize the logic a bit to work with a broader set of inputs.

```
type Target struct {
    Service string
    Type string
    Domain string
    Plan string
    Host string
    Region string
    Other string
}

func main() {
    input := `xxxxx:yyyyy:zzz.aaa.bbb.cc:dd:ee:ff`
    t := Target{}
    tokens := strings.Split(input, ":")
    t.Service = tokens[0]
    t.Type = tokens[1]
    subtokens := strings.Split(tokens[2], ".")
    t.Domain = subtokens[0]
    t.Plan = subtokens[1]
    t.Host = subtokens[2]
    t.Region = subtokens[3]
    t.Other = tokens[3]
    fmt.Printf("%v", t)
}
```

Working example here;
https://play.golang.org/p/57ZyOfdbvo

Comment: Was just typing sudo-code of this out for him. Didn't want to answer it in code that was both ugly and a valuable lesson to learn on ones own.

Comment: @NathanHyland yeah that might be a bit too accommodating. Thankfully there is the down vote feature to help balance things out :)