# How to split a string by multiple delimiters without deleting delimiters

Tags: go

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862613/how-to-split-a-string-by-multiple-delimiters-in-golang), but I want to do the same thing without removing the keys to split

I tried to use `FieldsFunc` but It deletes the keys.

Is there a easy way to achieve this behaviour?

Input

```
foo,bar:baz,,:
```

Expected

```
["foo," "bar:" "baz," "," ":"]
```

Comment: There are several answers on that question, not all of which delete delimiters. Is there a reason one of the other answers isn't sufficient?

Comment: ... or `strings.SplitAfter`, or manually index in a loop. There is an example in the [`strings` docs:](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#example-SplitAfter)

Comment: The [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53516002/13860) solution in that post can be easily adapted to not delete delimiters. Have you tried anything yet? Can you share your code?

Comment: I am not familiar with regex so I did not try yet

Answer (score 5):

```golang
s := "foo,bar:baz,,:"
fields := []string{}
last := 0
for i, r := range s {
    if r == ',' || r == ':' {
        fields = append(fields, s[last:i+1])
        last = i + 1
    }
}
fmt.Printf("%q\n", fields)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/8bePgKfR-kI